# How to get errorlevel from called file?

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

I'm trying to get the errorlevel after calling Maven from my batch file. Simplified example:

```
call mvn clean test
if errorlevel 0 echo Build success
```

The problem is, the error level will always be 0 even if the build fails. How can I access the errorlevel set by the called process?

Comment: You are experiencing on the of the quirks: "IF ERRORLEVEL construction has one strange feature, that can be used to our advantage: it returns TRUE if the return code was equal to or higher than the specified errorlevel." [About ErrorLevel](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third method:

```
if not errorlevel 1 echo no error
```

This is because errorlevel 0 is always true

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
call mvn clean test
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo Build success
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows 7, I find that 'if %errorlevel%==0 echo Build success' or what ever you want for output.

Hope this helps.